# Organization Profile Newsletters

Tags: administration, user-management, user-record, notification, organization-wide

**Organization Profile Settings - Newsletters**

The last I knew, you verified per User if they get any Newsletters.

Today, I was notified some of our users are getting the non-Admin Newsletter, so I checked, and it appears now that this is a GLOBAL setting.  I see conflicting information online about this setting being an "enabler" (so users can pick their own setting) versus a hardcoded "they WILL or WILL NOT get it".

Anyone have any authoritative information?  Assumption is, this has evolved at least twice in the past 5+ years based on my own experience.

[image]

Comment: Minor note:   This isn't the "answer", but I found out that... the person who emailed my users?  Yeah, he was spamming them on behalf of Salesforce, but NOT from their user info in our Org - those users had apparently gone to the SF site.  The states "they would not have been expecting the emails nor asked for them", so I give him credit for being forthcoming/honest.  (shrug)   Question still stands - I'd like to see documentation on how this "now works" officially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Employees who may have previously been in contact with Salesforce (prior to purchase or integration, for instance), they could end up on mailing lists NOT directly related to your Org, and receive emails that could be confused with actual Org newsletters.